# How do I build this simple mySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to select all rows where field A is 'x' and field B is one of 'w', 'y' or 'z'.
A and B are both strings, and I would like case to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE LOWER(A) = 'x'
   AND LOWER(B) IN ('w', 'y', 'z')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tablename where LCASE(A) ='x' and LCASE(B) in('w','y','z')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to select all rows where field A is 'x' and field B is one of 'w', 'y' or 'z'

```
... WHERE fldA = "x" AND fldB IN ("w", "y", "z") ...
```

> A and B are both strings, and I would like case to be ignored.

Just make sure that columns' collations are set to case insensitive type, eg *utf8_unicode_ci*, *utf8_german_ci*, *latin2_general_ci* (the suffix **_ci** is the key).